# jQuery validate submitHandler not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, bootstrap-modal

I've looked through some previous questions and I think I've verified the 'basic' things (submit button of correct type, in the form, etc), but I still cannot get the submitHandler to fire.

The form is being validated as desired, but on submit, it is not trigging the ajax call inside the submitHandler

Form Element:

```
<div id="view-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    Add New Version
                </h4>
            </div>

            <form method="post" class="form-horizontal validate_form" id="ajaxform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Version Number</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control required" name="version_number">
                                <option value="">Select A Version...</option>
                                '.writeSelectOptions('versions', 'id', 'version_number', 'launch_date', 'DESC', array(), $_GET['version_id']).'
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sort Order</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control required" name="sort_order" id="sort_order">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Change Details</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor">Help Text</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="add_change" />
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="ajaxsubmit" value="Submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#add_new_associated_change', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#view-modal').modal('show');
    });

    $('button#ajaxsubmit').click(function(){
        $('#ajaxform').validate({
            ignore: 'hidden',
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'scripts/submit_new_associated_change.php',
                    data: $('#ajaxform').serialize(),
                    success: function(msg){
                        $('#view-modal').modal('hide');
                        $('#versions').html(msg);
                        $('#status').html('<div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissable\"><button aria-hidden=\"true\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" class=\"close\" type=\"button\">&times;</button>Version added as requested.</div>');
                        //alert(msg);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log('failure'+xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( ".ckeditor" ) )
        .then(
        editor => {
        console.log( editor );
    }
    )
    .catch(
        error => {
        console.error( error );
    }
    );
</script>
```

For reference, the 'versions' and 'status' elements, are divs on another portion of the page that are to have content updated upon ajax submission.

Comment: I've started a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/5bbnczba/8/ but it's not working 100%. Fails on validating the form, which mine does not - likely how i set it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here...

```
$('button#ajaxsubmit').click(function(){
    $('#ajaxform').validate({
        ....
```

The `.validate()` method is only used to *initialize* the plugin on your form.  It does not belong inside of the `click` handler of the submit button.  Once properly initialized, the plugin itself *automatically* captures the `click`, blocks the submit, validates the form, and fires the `submitHandler`.

You are effectively doing nothing more than initializing the plugin on the first click; you'd need to click a second time to fire the validation and `submitHandler`.

Just remove the `click` handler...

```
$('#ajaxform').validate({
    ....
```

Your jsFiddle without the `click` handler:  **[jsfiddle.net/5bbnczba/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/5bbnczba/10/)**

---

It's a moot point because your `click` handler is not needed, but your jQuery selector, `$('button#ajaxsubmit')`, was completely wrong.  You were targeting a `button` element with `id="ajaxsubmit"`, however, your submit is an `<input>`, not a `<button>`.

Comment: Removing the click handler fixed the issue, thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

In your html, it is defined as input, so button#xxx is not right

change your

```
 $('button#ajaxsubmit').click(function(){
```

to the following works

```
 $('#ajaxsubmit').click(function(){
 $('input#ajaxsubmit').click(function(){
 $('input[id=ajaxsubmit]').click(function(){
```